# Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.2.1

Tags: android, ads, applovin, ironsource

I am trying to add the ironsource adapter in the android app. While trying to add the app, I am getting the following errors.

I am using the following versions

```
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:11.4.0.0'
implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:ironsource-adapter:7.2.2.1.0'
```

Errors:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':App:DebugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.2.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/7.2.2.1/mediationsdk-7.2.2.1.pom'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/7.2.2.1/mediationsdk-7.2.2.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':App:DebugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.2.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

it took my 1 hour for find this error !

in settings.gradle, please add : **maven { url "https://android-sdk.is.com" }** in **repositories**

My file settings.gradle :

> pluginManagement {
> repositories {
> google()
> mavenCentral()
> gradlePluginPortal()
> maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }
> maven { url "https://android-sdk.is.com" }
> maven { url "https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea"
> }
> maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle" }
> } } dependencyResolutionManagement {
> repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
> repositories {
> google()
> mavenCentral()
> maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }
> maven { url "https://android-sdk.is.com" }
> maven { url "https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea"
> }
> maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle" }
> } }